# Protractor data driven - without passing data to each page object

Tags: typescript, protractor

For protractor test suite using typescript, reading data from Excel sheet:

```
let appData:any = extractData.getData();

for (let i in data) {

describe('Login', () => {
        libraryLogin.login();
    });

    describe('Application', () => {
        libraryApp.application();
    });
}
```

One way to pass appData which has data rows as Json object is pass it as an argument like libraryApp.application(appData).

Is there any other way for the page objects to access appData instead of passing it to each page object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jasmine - data provider**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider